# Command to set server authentication to SQL Server and Windows authentication mode

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

Is there any way to check this radio button with a T-SQL command? I'm trying to script our database setup and this was one of the things that hung me up.

[image]

Comment: Do you see the "Script" button on the top of that dialog?  It's there to help you with this.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT CASE SERVERPROPERTY('IsIntegratedSecurityOnly')   
WHEN 1 THEN 'Windows Authentication'   
WHEN 0 THEN 'Windows and SQL Server Authentication'  
END as [Authentication Mode]
```

https://www.sqlserverlogexplorer.com/recognize-authentication-mode-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 2):

To change the setting you need to change the registry, which can be done in SQL Server with:

```
USE [master]
GO
EXEC xp_instance_regwrite N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer', N'LoginMode', REG_DWORD, 2
GO
```

As mentioned in the comment, making the change in the UI, and then "Script action to New Query Window" will give you this answer as well.